# How to select specific column headers in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to select specific column headers from a view in oracle.  It works when I have 1 column but if I add more column names I get back nothing.

I have tried add adding more AND column_name like '%%' but like I said earlier having more than 1 column name doesn't work.  I tried replacing ALL_TAB_COLUMNS with USER_TAB_COLUMNS

```
SELECT column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VW_CATALOG' AND column_name like '%SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE%'
```

Ideally I would like to have this work below:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VW_CATALOG' 
AND column_name like '%SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE%'
AND column_name like '%SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB%'
AND column_name like '%SCBCRSE_TITLE%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'And' selects things where both the given conditions are true. It sounds like you're looking for 'Or'.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VW_CATALOG' 
AND (column_name like '%SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE%'
  OR column_name like '%SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB%'
  OR column_name like '%SCBCRSE_TITLE%'
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Definitely still need to learn alot of sql